# Voting tooltip changes meaning of downvote

Tags: bug, status-completed, downvotes, tooltips

In the new voting tooltips, a crucial reason for downvoting was left out:

> **This question does not show any research effort**

I suspect the UI designer(s) removed the bit out to save space, not realizing it changes the meaning of the button.

New text (as of today):

> Downvote this question if you find it unclear or not useful.

Old text:

> This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear, or not helpful.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349527/566903

Comment: Also the text changes after you downvote it (to just "not useful") making it even less clear.

Comment: @pppery This is a bug report, while that link asks for the reasoning for the change.

Comment: Not only that. It's **not** a tool-tip anymore. It's an instant pop-up. It's not only annoying, it's also insulting. As if one cannot remember what the buttons do and needs to be reminded the **instant** one hovers over the buttons. This will make me hover less, and effectively also vote less.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery This is **so not useful**!!!

Comment: This change is being rolled back. [Details are here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349800/312743).